# Geometry and calculus definition

Tags: calculus, geometry

I have a question here
Can we define the tangent line and the secant line as follow

secant line:is a line that intersect function at two points

tangent line: is a line that touches the function at one point

Please if there is something wrong , where is the mistake and if there are counterexamples will be great

Comment: No, the inverse of what you said.

Comment: $y=2$ is tangent to $f(x)=x^3-3x$ at $x=-1$, but also $f(2)=2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Secant line : is a line that intersects with a given function at **least** two points.

> tangent line: is a line that touches the function at one point

This is completely wrong (if 'touches' meant intersects, without further specification), consider $y=x^2$ and $x=0$. In your definition, $x=0$ is tangent line of $y=x^2$.

Comment: okay thank you very much but isn't at two points by default it means at least two points?

Comment: In English when we say for example, 

If you score a point, you will win. 

This means by default that you need to score at least “one” point to satisfy the condition and win. 

However you can still score 2,3, 4, ... points. am I right?

Comment: @herwitzgalgon I would say it is bit ambiguous to write like that (at least in mathematics). The most precise way of writing will be like this : Let a curve $C=C(t)$ and a line $L=L(t)$ is given, where $t$ is parameter. $L$ is secant line of $C$, if and only if there exists two points $p,q$, such that $p\neq q$ , $C(p)=L(p)$, and $C(q)=L(q)$. If you have some time to devote, please try to learn first order logic. It can eliminate lots of ambiguities generated by natural languages while doing mathematics.

Comment: Okay I got it, in the second definition : is at one point means at least one point or it means exactly one point? for example in probability Lets take this example
Two different coins are tossed randomly. Find the probability of:
getting one tail  the answer is 1/2
getting at least 1 tail the answer is 3/4
if one tail means at least then the two answers should be same

Comment: There is no second definition in my answer, I just commented on what you have wrote. To define tangent line rigorusly, you need a differentiability of the curve. If you haven't learned it yet, then try to understand what 'touch' means by looking at the pictures.

Comment: no I meant in my question I know it is wrong but I'm asking from a logical perspective is at one point means exactly one point or at least?

Comment: So are you asking the statement 'tangent line: is a line that touches the function at one point' does not contain any ambiguity?

Comment: I'm asking in general is at one point contains any ambiguity , does at one point means at least or exactly according to the probability question or in any other fileds in mathematics I meant when we say at one point or at two points are these statements means at least or exact point/points

Comment: I will say depends on the context. But it can't be bad to be more precise. Usually if you want to write 'at least one point', then you say 'there exists a point'. If you want to write 'exactly one point', then you say 'there exists a unique point', or just as 'exactly one point'.

Comment: Can we say that the second definition in my question also have another mistake which the function must be differentiable at that point for example abs(x) and y=0

Comment: @herwitzgalgon Yes.